# Web-based user manual

Tags: php

I have completed one of my projects in PHP. Now I want make a web based user manual. How can I do that?

Comment: Manuel is a guy from Barcelona. I assume you mean manual :-) Let me fix that for you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is heresy in a technical environment like S.O. but I'd concentrate on the actual content of the manual first, and then use that to decide how best to 'deliver' it.

For example, if you have a lot of screenshots or embedded video, you might take a different approach than if you had a a lot of field specific help text which might make more sense within the context of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

[Opera has a good introduction to writing webpages](http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum//). You just need to know about the basic structure of a page, headings, paragraph, and links. Knowing `kbd` and `code` would probably be useful too.